# "Perfect separation" error when using Matcher from pymatch (Propensity score matching)

Tags: python, matching, propensity-score-matching

I am trying to use the [pymatch](https://medium.com/@bmiroglio/introducing-the-pymatch-package-6a8c020e2009) package but I keep getting the error `Error: Perfect separation detected, results not available`. I checked multiple times, my dataset is not equal. It contains 260k rows for Control and 50k for treatment and has different averages. I only have 5 variables, all `integers` or `Floats` rounded to 2 decimals.

My goal is to match some treated customers to non-treated customers for further analysis based on propensity score matching.

I already removed outliers as apparently it cannot handle these well. I also rounded Decimals to 2 positions after the comma. I tried using only 2 variables of the whole dataset. Nothing worked.

```py
d = {'Customer': ['A','B','C','D'], 'Basket_Size': [30, 40,25,30], 'Miles_away': [5.2, 15.4,16.3,7.2], 'was_treated': [1, 0,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

test = df[df.was_treated== 1]
control = df[df.was_treated== 0]

m = Matcher(test, control, yvar="was_treated", exclude=['Customer'])
## until here it runs perfectly fine

# output:

#Formula:
#was_treated~ Basket_Size+Miles_away
#n majority: 2
#n minority: 2


## this now throws the error
np.random.seed(20170925)
m.fit_scores(balance=True, nmodels=20)

# output: 
# Error: Perfect separation detected, results not available
# Fitting Models on Balanced Samples: 1\20
```

I expect an output like `Average Accuracy: 78%` but I get `Average Accuracy: nan%`  and the error `Error: Perfect separation detected, results not available`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue myself. By the nature of the data, one `variable` was affected by the treatment. Meaning that no datapoint in `was_treated== 1` could have a `Miles_away >10` and vice versa, no datapoint in `was_treated== 0` could have `Miles_away <10`. This was the perfect separation. Excluding this `variable` from the propensity scoring solved the issue.

```py
    m = Matcher(test, control, yvar="fast_delivery", exclude=['CUSTOMER_NUMBER','Miles_away'])
```